# Can I make a MacroOptions shortcut work in active workbook when another workbook is open with the same shortcut

Tags: excel, vba

The following paragraph added to explain the issue without the details.
A shortcut key (Ctrl+Shift+Z) exists in two workbooks and both work as expected when opened separately.  However, if both workbooks are open the shortcut always fails and always in the same workbook.  The order the workbooks are opened does not matter.

The following command has been executed in two different workbooks. The Public Subroutines executed have different names and only exist in their respective workbooks.

```
Application.MacroOptions Macro:="SelectAndReveal", ShortcutKey:="Z"  'Ctrl+Shift+Z
```

Opening order doesn't matter; wkbkA then wkbkB *or* wkbkB then wkbkA.  The shortcut only works in wkbkA. If wkbkA is closed, it immediately begins working as expected in wkbkB.

This code was even added to "ThisWorkbook" of wkbkB, compiled, and saved.  It still doesn't work in wkbkB if WkbkA is open.

```
Private Sub Workbook_open()
   Application.MacroOptions Macro:="SelectAndReveal", ShortcutKey:=""   'Clear Shortcut
   Application.MacroOptions Macro:="SelectAndReveal", ShortcutKey:="Z"  'Ctrl+Shift+Z
End Sub
```

Must the shortcut be set and cleared in Workbook_Activate and Workbook_Deactivate events to ensure the shortcut works?  Why doesn't it work in the active workbook, or at least the last workbook opened?

PS.  I want to use Ctrl+Shift+Z because, as I recall, there were only two Ctrl or Ctrl+Shift keystrokes that don't compete with Excel or the system.  Plus, the other keystroke requires two hands.

FYI:  It only executes in wkbkA when wkbkA is active.

Final footnote:  Until this issue was encountered today the MacroOptions command had been set once.  It was not executed by code since the first execution.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to clear the shortcut when the workbook loses focus (no longer active) and reset it when it regains focus.

Ok so it is a very minor bug.  How the bug manifests itself is very strange.  When both workbooks are opened the shortcut always works in one workbook but *never* the other regardless of the order the workbooks are opened.